# SharePoint 2010 Service Application fault exeption

Tags: development, web-config, service-application

I am receiving an error from my SP 2010 Service Application when I try to execute the code from my proxy.

> An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail. ystem.ServiceModel.FaultException: An error occurred when verifying security for the message.

I have done some searching some say this is an obscure WCF error thrown when the server and client's clocks are off, but I am getting this error when the server and client are running on the same machine. I have no service references to update, so that isn't the issue either.

Can anyone help me out here?

Here is the code in my proxy where the error gets thrown:

```
    public string ConvertToTLForm(string inputDocument, string tipAndLeadLibrary, string siteCollectionURL)
    {

        // execute the call against the service app
        ExecuteOnChannel("ConvertToTLForm",
            delegate(ITipAndLeadAPIContract channel)
            {
                channel.ConvertToTLForm(inputDocument, tipAndLeadLibrary, siteCollectionURL);
            });

        return "";
    }
```

Here is my web.config file for my service application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> <configuration>   <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" defaultLanguage="C#" />   </system.web>   <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="TLAPITypeBehaviors" >
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="AF.TipAndLeadAPI.TipAndLeadAPIServiceApplication" behaviorConfiguration="TLAPITypeBehaviors">
        <endpoint binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="TLAPIServiceHttpBinding"
                  contract="AF.TipAndLeadAPI.ITipAndLeadAPIContract"
                  address="" />
        <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="TLAPIServiceHttpBinding">
          <security authenticationMode="IssuedToken" allowInsecureTransport="true" />
          <binaryMessageEncoding>
            <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="1048576" maxArrayLength="2097152" />
          </binaryMessageEncoding>
          <httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2162688" authenticationScheme="Anonymous" useDefaultWebProxy="false" />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>   </system.serviceModel>   <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <authentication>
        <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />
        <windowsAuthentication enabled="false" />
      </authentication>
    </security>   </system.webServer> </configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I made a rookie mistake. My client.congfig file in my Hive 14/WebClients folder had a different authenticationMode then my web.config file in my Hive 14/WebServices folder. Once I changed them both to "IssueTokenOverTransport" this issue was resolved. Hope it helps!